# How can I build a github action by using a public docker registry container?

Tags: dockerfile, github-actions, dockerhub, building-github-actions

I am trying to create a simple docker action but instead of using the local Dockerfile in the repository I want to use a public on dockehub. I have created two repositories:

1. docker-creator: which has the docker action
2. docker-user: which is a job that uses docker-creator

This is my action.yml in docker-creator:

```
name: 'Hello World'
description: 'Greet someone and record the time'
inputs:
  who-to-greet:  # id of input
    description: 'Who to greet'
    required: true
    default: 'World'
outputs:
  time: # id of output
    description: 'The time we greeted you'
runs:
  using: 'docker'
  image: 'docker://alpine:3.10'
  args:
    - ${{ inputs.who-to-greet }}
```

In the image param typically you will see 'Dockerfile' but in my example you see I have replaced it with a public docker registry container.

When I use docker-creator from docker-user I get this error[docker-creator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU6eC.png)

This is the main.yml workflow in docker-user:

```
  hello_world_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: A job to say hello
    steps:
      - name: Hello world action step
        id: hello
        uses: bryanaexp/docker-creator@main
        with:
          who-to-greet: 'Cat'
      # Use the output from the `hello` step
      - name: Get the output time
        run: echo "The time was ${{ steps.hello.outputs.time }}"
```

I have tried looking for help online but alot of it is only using dockerfile. Also I have referred to this documentation https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-public-docker-registry-container but no use.

LINKS:
Docker Action : https://github.com/bryanaexp/docker-creator/blob/main/action.yml
Github Action Using Docker Action: https://github.com/bryanaexp/docker-user

These are the following steps I have taken to resolve my problem:
1 - I have read through a lot of github action documentation

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-public-docker-registry-container
  2 - Done various tests on my code using different parameters
  3 - Researched stackoverflow but only found a similar example but that uses a private docker registry.